# Nested Hash to Nested Array: How to access individual values

Tags: ruby

I apologize in advance for the newbie question!

I have the following nested hash and want to convert it into a nested array, and be able to access individual values using their indices.

```
vehicles = {
    car: { type: 'sedan', color: 'red', year: 2007 },
  }
```

I attempted to do this a couple of different ways below, however, I was not able to access an individual value, like 'sedan' using its index. My questions are 1) How do I access an individual element in each solution? 2) Is it recommended to use .map as I have or to_a for future cases?

```
 car_array1 = vehicles.to_a
 # => [[:car, {:type=>"sedan", :color=>"red", :year=>2007}]] 

 car_array2 = []
 vehicles.map { |k, v| car_array2 << [k, v] }
 # => [[[:car, {:type=>"sedan", :color=>"red", :year=>2007}]]] 

 puts 'car_array1:'
 p car_array1[0][1]
 # {:type=>"sedan", :color=>"red", :year=>2007}

 puts '-' * 10 

 puts 'car_array2'
 p car_array2[0][1]
 # {:type=>"sedan", :color=>"red", :year=>2007}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve as a result?

Comment: I'm curious about how the conversion from a hash to array works. I was expecting an array, such as [:type, 'sedan'], [:color, 'blue'], [:year, 2003]] when using .to_a. I'm confused as to why there are curly braces after the conversion?

Comment: Ok, that's a simple question and i will answer it right now. If you have other questions, than you should ask it in comments.

Comment: I don't understand how you have them in the hash to begin with. What happens if you have more than one car?

Comment: Do you want simply `vehicles[:car].to_a #=> [[:type, "sedan"], [:color, "red"], [:year, 2007]]`?

Comment: Why do you need to convert to an array? Do you care that color is the 2nd attribute? Why not just use `vehicles[:car][:color]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vehicles = {
   car: { type: 'sedan', color: 'red', year: 2007 },
 }
```

Here you have a hash with nested hash in it: `vehicles[:car]`. When you attempt to convert it to array with `.to_a` you convert only higher level of this hash but not nested. To achieve what you want you can convert nested hashes also by doing this:

```
result = vehicles.to_a.map { |v| v.last.to_a }
=> [[[:type, "sedan"], [:color, "red"], [:year, 2007]]]
```

Either way you are not doing your solution the right way. It seems too strange and complex, but I don't know your case, so ...

Comment: or `vehicles.values.map(&:to_a)`.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! I’m not doing anything with the data; I’m simply trying to understand how the conversion works and your explanation made it a bit more clear! One thing, say I leave the nested array as is how would I access an individual value? `[[:car, {:type=>"sedan", :color=>"red", :year=>2007}]]`

Comment: @Ralitza Dont get it fully but maybe something like this? `a= [[:car, {:type=>"sedan", :color=>"red", :year=>2007}]]; a.first.last[:type]` or `a.first.last.to_a`

Comment: Ah, that's great! Thank you so much for answering all of my questions!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear, but based on your comment, you want something like this:

```
vehicles[:car].to_a
```

Which yields this:

```
[[:type, "sedan"], [:color, "red"], [:year, 2007]]
```

Comment: Yes, I’m sorry for not being more clear - I had so many questions in mind and wasn’t quite able to articulate them properly. Thank you for this!